# Using NSURLSession (in Swift) to get data

Tags: swift, httprequest, nsurlsession

I've been searching around to learn how to get some data using NSURLSession in Swift.
There is a general pattern being repeated on the internet for making an http request using NSURLSession, and it looks a lot like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myPretendURLthatIsNotThisURL.com")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))}
task.resume()
```

If I place a real URL in, I can see a lot of JSON output printed, which is the expected response from the server.  Nice : )  I can see the data from println().  However, I would rather display the returned data in a text view when I press a button.  I do believe my solution relies on using a delegate (somehow).
Is it all right to request an example of how this is done, in the following context:

1. Code is in Swift
2. Press a button (IBAction, contains the code above to make the request)
3. Display the data returned (it's JSON, I'll worry how to parse it later on) in a text view.

Thanks!

Comment: Exchange the code after the `in` keyword with the code to fill the text view. And read some introduction books.

Comment: i am also having problems with NSURLSession - i don't understand how to get data to some variable